# Create multiple fixed width div of equal size dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

How to create multiple(n number) fixed width div of equal size which fits the entire screen without gap and also i have to fill each div with some random background colors.

Comment: Which language do you use?

Comment: I have to do this by using html5,css and jquery

Comment: Are you using jquery mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should works:

```
// Function to get a random HEX color
function get_random_color() {
    // Make an array with all the HEX values
    var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
    // Put the # before our color string
    var color = '#';
    // Get 6 random HEX values and append to our color string
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
        color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
    }
    // Return the random color
    return color;
}

// Declare the number of columns, the container and calc the width of each column
var columns = 10, container = $("#container"), width = (100 / columns);

// Append to <head> a <style> tag with the rule for the width of the columns
$("head").append("<style>.col { width: " + width + "% }</style>");

// Generate N columns and append them to $container
for(var i = 0; i < columns; i++) {

    container.append("<div class=\"col\" style=\"background: " + get_random_color() + "\">Quick brown fox</div>");

}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/6JzMB/2/

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about using prepend to add a style rule for a specific class within an element!

Comment: I've changed to append the `<style>` element to `<head>`

Comment: This code is working fine but i need to create div in 'n' number of rows throughout the screen height.By using this code i can get div for only one row

Comment: do you need horizontal or vertical divs?

Comment: better, write a fiddle with the result you want using plan HTML and CSS, so I can translate it in jQuery.

Comment: I need divs throughout the page like grid view(both horizontal and vertical)  and have to perform an action, if i click on a div it has to display a message.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript/jQuery, set up a script that sets up the number of divs. Divide the number by 100 and then assign that number as the width property of each div (in percentage).

This will give you (depending on the number) between 99-100% coverage. If you want full coverage then modify the script so that the last div generated has it's width set to auto instead.

The below code is an example, not tested so you will need to implement it however you need to. This is just a guideline.

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    if(i === n-1){
        $('body').append('<div style="width:auto">');
    }
    else{
        var dynamicWidth = n / 100;
        $('body').append('<div style="width:"+dynamicWidth+"%">');
    }
}
```

Comment: Added to my original answer.

Comment: and add a % after dynamicWidth, else it wouldn't do much ;)

Comment: Thanks, will add that in!

Comment: you have mixed `'` and `"`, fix it (:

Comment: How to calculate n value?

Comment: @FezVrasta I'm using " " within ' ' what's the issue? and user2089987 the value of n is n / 100 (n divided by 100). I assign this to the dynamicWidth variable.

Comment: @BenM would be, also, probably better append `<div [...] />` with the trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

you'd need html:

```
<div id="holder"></div>
```

and js:

```
var colors = new Array("ff0000","00ff00","0000ff","ff00ff","beeeef");
//instead of colors, use the randomColor function "Fez Vrasta" posted
var n = 5;

for(var i=0;i<n;i++){
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "inlineDiv";
    div.style.backgroundColor = "#" + colors[i];
    div.style.width = ($('#holder').width() / n) + "px";
    div.style.height = "500px";
    document.getElementById('holder').appendChild(div);
}
```

and some css:

```
.inlineDiv {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
#holder {
    width:100%;
}
```

...here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2YQbx/